# Decoding a JSON on Swift

Tags: json, swift, api

In the last days I've been trying to decode a JSON file through to an uikit app but kept failing wherever I've tried to do. can someone please help me out?

this is my decoding func:

```
   override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        cidadelabel.text = city!
        downloadJSON {
            print("success")
        }
        print(result.main?.temp!)
        // var temperatura = result?.main?.temp
        // temperatura = temperatura! - 273.15
        // temperatureLabel.text = "\(String(temperatura!))°C"
    }
    
    func downloadJSON(completed: @escaping () -> ()){
        let url = URL(string: "https://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/weather?appid=******d&q=" + city!)
        URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: url!) {
            data, response, error in
            if error == nil{
                do{
                    print(data!)
                    print(response!)
                    
                    self.result = try JSONDecoder().decode(Response.self, from: data!)
                    
                    DispatchQueue.main.async {
                        completed()
                    }
                }
                catch {
                    print("error fetching data from the api")
                    print(String(describing: error))
                }
            }
        }.resume()
    }
```

this is my class receiving the JSON:

```
import Foundation

struct Response: Codable {
    
    var coord: Coord?
    var weather: [WeatherBase]?
    var main: Main?
    var visibility: Int?
    var wind: Wind?
    var rain: Rain?
    var clouds: Clouds?
    var dt: Int?
    var sys: Sys?
    var timezone: Int?
    var id: Int?
    var name: String?
    var cod: Int?

}

struct Coord: Codable {
    var lon: Double?
    var lat: Double?
}

struct WeatherBase: Codable {
    var id: String { _id! }
    private var _id: String?
    var base: String?
    
    mutating func prepare() {
        _id = _id ?? UUID().uuidString
    }
}

struct Weather: Codable {
    var id: Int?
    var main: String?
    var description: String?
    var icon: String?
}

struct Main: Codable {
    var temp: Double?
    var feels_like: Double?
    var temp_min: Double?
    var temp_max: Double?
    var pressure: Int?
    var humidity: Int?
}

struct Wind: Codable {
    var speed: Double?
    var deg: Int?
}

struct Rain: Codable{
    var umh: Int?
}

struct Clouds: Codable {
    var all: Int?
}

struct Sys: Codable {
    var type: Int?
    var id: Int?
    var country: String?
    var sunrise: Int?
    var sunset: Int?
    
}
```

and this is the JSON:

```
{"coord":{"lon":-35.7353,"lat":-9.6658},"weather":[{"id":801,"main":"Clouds","description":"few clouds","icon":"02d"}],"base":"stations","main":{"temp":302.84,"feels_like":305.59,"temp_min":302.84,"temp_max":302.84,"pressure":1011,"humidity":61},"visibility":10000,"wind":{"speed":7.2,"deg":90},"clouds":{"all":20},"dt":1672689129,"sys":{"type":1,"id":8413,"country":"BR","sunrise":1672646788,"sunset":1672692412},"timezone":-10800,"id":3395981,"name":"Maceió","cod":200}
```

the response is telling me that everything is nil (optionals) as it is getting a different result from the api which makes no sense cause when I enter the same link given it gives me the right json

> Response(coord: nil, weather: nil, main: nil, visibility: nil, wind: nil, rain: nil, clouds: nil, dt: nil, sys: nil, timezone: nil, id: nil, name: nil, cod: nil)

```
<NSHTTPURLResponse: 0x600003837c80> { URL: https://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/weather?appid=b**************d&q=Maceio } { Status Code: 200, Headers {
    "Access-Control-Allow-Credentials" =     (
        true
    );
    "Access-Control-Allow-Methods" =     (
        "GET, POST"
    );
    "Access-Control-Allow-Origin" =     (
        "*"
    );
    Connection =     (
        "keep-alive"
    );
    "Content-Length" =     (
        472
    );
    "Content-Type" =     (
        "application/json; charset=utf-8"
    );
    Date =     (
        "Mon, 02 Jan 2023 21:46:06 GMT"
    );
    Server =     (
        openresty
    );
    "X-Cache-Key" =     (
        "/data/2.5/weather?q=maceio"
    );
} }
        "/data/2.5/weather?q=maceio"
    );
} }
```

Comment: The reason everything is nil and you don't get an error printed is because you made everything optional in your Codable types so if you for instance have misspelled a property the decoder will just think that the corresponding key is not present in the json. So change your types so no properties are optionals unless you know for sure that they can be nil. Doing so and running the code will print an error that hopefully explains what is wrong.

Comment: Received this now: error fetching data from the api
keyNotFound(CodingKeys(stringValue: "_id", intValue: nil), Swift.DecodingError.Context(codingPath: [CodingKeys(stringValue: "weather", intValue: nil), _JSONKey(stringValue: "Index 0", intValue: 0)], debugDescription: "No value associated with key CodingKeys(stringValue: \"_id\", intValue: nil) (\"_id\").", underlyingError: nil)). I thought i had solved this error earlier but it seens I have just hid it under the optionals, can you help me fix it? It's under JSON formatting

Comment: You don't use `Weather` but `WeatherBase`?

Comment: Question details should be [edit]ed into the question body -- not written as comments -- so that the full story is in one place.

Answer (score 0):

First, you should remove "YOUR-SECRET-TOKEN" from your post.

Second, you need to understand that `downloadJSON` is asynchronous functions,
and will have the `results` available ONLY after it is finished/completed.

The following code shows how to use the asynchronous function with a completion handler,
to fetch the weather json data and make it available to your code in `viewDidLoad()`.

Note also, that if your `city` name is not correct, you will also get an error decoding the result.

Note that there is no need for all fields of the `Response` to be optional, read the docs and find which one is optional and amend your code to that.

```
func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    cidadelabel.text = city!
    downloadJSON { error in
        if error == nil {
            print("success")
            
            // -- here `result` are available inside this closure, after they have been fetched
            
             print(result?.main?.temp!)
             var temperatura = result?.main?.temp
             temperatura = temperatura! - 273.15
             temperatureLabel.text = "\(String(temperatura!))°C"
        } else {
            print("error: \(error)")
        }
    }
}

func downloadJSON(completed: @escaping (Error?) -> ()){
    let token = "YOUR-SECRET-TOKEN"
    if let url = URL(string: "https://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/weather?appid=\(token)&q=" + city!) {
        URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: url) { data, response, error in
            if error == nil, let data = data {
                do {
                    self.result = try JSONDecoder().decode(Response.self, from: data)
                    completed(nil) // <-- no error, all good
                }
                catch {
                    completed(error)  // <-- with error
                }
            }
        }.resume()
    }
}


struct Response: Codable {
    var coord: Coord?
    var weather: [Weather]?  // <-- here
    var main: Main?
    var visibility: Int?
    var wind: Wind?
    var rain: Rain?
    var clouds: Clouds?
    var dt: Int?
    var sys: Sys?
    var timezone: Int?
    var id: Int?
    var name: String?
    var cod: Int?
}
```

Comment: I see you have taken my advice to remove "YOUR-SECRET-TOKEN" from your post. Did my answer not work for you?